# Context help for every jComponent with questionmark cursor

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Most windows users may remember that every windows 98 properties/settings window had a little question mark button next to other window buttons:

[image: image description]

If you clicked on that button, all click events were overriden by different callback for that window. And that new callback would display element's individual help text.

I'd like to do the very same. My idea was to do it using class which holds all `JComponent` and `Help` associations:

```
public interface Help {
  /** based on implementation, displays help to the used. May use
   *  JDialog, url redirection or maybe open document on the computer.**/
  public void getHelp(JComponent comp, ActionEvent evt);
}

public class HelpLibrary {
  public HashMap<JComponent, Help> helpLib;
  public void getHelp(JComponent comp, ActionEvent evt) {
    Help help = helpLib.get(comp);
    if(help!=null) {
       help.getHelp(comp, evt);
    }
  }
}
```

Writing these two classes was the easy part. The hard one is this:

1. How to override all click events in particular window and then remove override after help was called?
2. How to ensure help cursor will override all other cursors, and again, safely remove this setting?

I have no idea where to start with this. I really do not want to change the GUI structure or used classes just because of this, which is why I want to store the help and do the overrides from the outside.

```
public class HelpLibrary {
  /** 
   * Overrides click events on the given window and displays help cursor.
   * User then may click a JComponent, such as button, to initiate
   * help callback for that element. If no help exists for that element,
   * do nothing and stop the help mode.
   * @param window the window to get help for
  **/
  public void waitForHelp(JFrame window) {
     ???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

1. Register a global MouseListener using
   `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myListener, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK)`
2. Cast the incoming event to MouseEvent and check the event type using the getID() method
3. If the event is a click for a component, which has help, you need to show help, consume event and remove this listener from the global listener list.
4. You can also override mouseEnter/Exit event in this
   listener for components which have help text, and set the cursor to
   question/normal type (don't forget to consume this event).

This is only idea for you, I've not tested whether it works.

Comment: How does one *consume* the event? And how can I let it *pass through* (not consume)?

Comment: Use `MouseEvent.consume()` to consume event (method is defined in parent `InputEvent`). If you don't do it - the event will be proceed by the swing components

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `GlassPane`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). The Glass Pane demo shows how to intercept mouse events and redispatch the event to the underlying components. YoOu would obviously change this code to find the component under the mouse click and then display the help context.

The glass pane can be toggeled on/off by making it visible or not.

Comment: Something tells me that this would make the window appear frozen as the object would stop responding on mouse hovering.